# Image doesn't show in Rails mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Creditor, Paperclip, and Mailer (send grid) to create content and mail it to subscribers. I am uploading an image to my server and it shows on the website correctly in `:content`, however users receive a blank image in their email.

This is my mailer body:

```
<body>
    <h3>Hi <%= @listener.name %>, </h3>
    <p><h3>You have received a message from <%= @message.speaker.organization %></p></h3><br/>
    <!-- <p><%= @message.speaker.fullname %> has sent a message to you.</p><br/> -->
    <h3 style="color: #000;">Description: <strong style="font-size: 12px; color: #444;"><%= @message.description %></strong></h3><hr/>
    <p style="font-size: 12px;"><%= raw @message.content %></p><br/>
</body>
```

And my mailer:

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "meditate@messagefollower.com"

  def mail_message_to_listener(message, listener)
    @message = message
    @listener = listener
    if @message.image?
      message_image_path = @message.get_image_path
      attachments[@message.image_file_name] = File.read(message_image_path)
    end
    mail(to: @listener.email, subject: "#{@message.title}, Part 1")
  end

  def mail_message_part_to_listener(messagepart, listener)
    @messagepart = messagepart
    @listener = listener
    message_title = @messagepart.message.title
    part_number = @messagepart.part_no
    if @messagepart.image?
      message_part_image_path = @messagepart.get_image_path
      attachments[@messagepart.image_file_name] = File.read(message_part_image_path)
    end
    mail(to: @listener.email, subject: "#{part_number.ordinalize} part of #{message_title}, Part #{part_number+1}")
  end
end
```

my config.js for creditor

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  //config.language = 'es'; //this could be any language
  config.width = '650';
  config.height = '500';
  config.baseHref = 'http://messagefollower.com';



  // Filebrowser routes
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

// You could delete or reorder any of this elements as you wish
  config.toolbar_Menu = [
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
    { name: 'editing', items: ['SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
    { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-'] }, '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] }, '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'] }
  ];
  config.toolbar = 'Menu';
  return true;
};
```

my attachment.rb

```
class Ckeditor::AttachmentFile < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                    :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 100.megabytes
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :data

  def url_thumb
    @url_thumb ||= Ckeditor::Utils.filethumb(filename)
  end
end
```

Comment: So it's in the `message.content` attribute?  It'll be using a relative url.  You'll need to configure it not to.  Looks like you can set it from the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-baseHref)

Comment: ok i will give it a try

Comment: i see, I specified absolute url in my config.js i have config.baseHref = 'messagefollower.com/public/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/…;; line, but in ckeditor as a source it shows src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/10/content_kolom-300-400x400.jpg" Where do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is because of URLs in your `@message.content` are not absolute,  they don't include the hostname.

Set CKEditor's `config.baseHref` to your site address, it defaults to empty.

Other way is to preprocess the content and change `href="/some/path"` to `href="http://your.address.com/some/path"`.

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: HI, i added config.baseHref = 'http://messagefollower.com'; but still image didn't display in email. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Boris to test it you do not need to send email - you want absolute links in html, so look at `img` tags inside `@message.content`. If you cannot make ckeditor make these right, then modify it before sending

Comment: What i have in img tags is <img alt="" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/content_1_1_3-9_final.jpg" style="float:left; height:460px; width:300px" />  I will try to figure it out.

Comment: so my file path should be one of these paths? has_attached_file :data,
                    :url => "/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"

Comment: @Boris no, you need it to be a full url with protocol, domain name and so on

Comment: in my attachment_file.rb it points to :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"  , however on my server when i go to /app/messagefollowerlive/current/public/ckeditor_assets i only see picture folder, and i don't see attachments folder, is that what causing a problem? it basically doesn't upload to the server?

Comment: do i simply need to create attachments folder on the server? and keep this path config.baseHref = 'http://messagefollower.com/public/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename';

Comment: i did as you suggested to change path to point to the file path on the server where images are stored. My images are displaying alright  on the website and server, but in email its blank.  Any other ideas?

Comment: idea is the same - you need absolute urls. Browser already know the address of your site, thus it can understand paths, but email client does not.

Comment: i see, I specified absolute url in my config.js  i have config.baseHref = 'http://messagefollower.com/public/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:filename'; line, but in ckeditor as a source it shows src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/10/content_kolom-300-400x400.jpg" Where do i fix it?